# How to Conditionally Route Using One Button? (Flutter)

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a scene (collections.dart) that takes an index of several other scenes/files in a `PageView.builder`. You can swipe between scenes from the collections.dart file.  Also in collections.dart is a button.

I want it to be the case that if you click on the button, and the current scene being shown through collections.dart is, for example, `FirstScreen`, then I can route to a table I have built specifically for first.dart, with the same being true for all other scenes in the index.

I have tried to accomplish this by a conditional statement in the `onPressed` argument, but no success yet. There is no error, it just takes no action.  Here is the code in its entirety for collections.dart (including the unsuccessful conditional statement for `onPressed`):

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:circle_indicator/circle_indicator.dart';
    import 'first.dart';
    import 'second.dart';
    import 'third.dart';
    import 'fourth.dart';
    import 'fifth.dart';
    import 'sixth.dart';
    import 'seventh.dart';
    import 'eighth.dart';
    import 'ninth.dart';
    import 'tenth.dart';


    class CollectionsScreen extends StatelessWidget {

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return Collections();
      }
    }

    class Collections extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      CollectionsState createState() => CollectionsState();
    }

    class CollectionsState extends State<Collections> {

      FirstScreen one;
      SecondScreen two;
      ThirdScreen three;
      FourthScreen four;
      FifthScreen five;
      SixthScreen six;
      SeventhScreen seven;
      EighthScreen eight;
      NinthScreen nine;
      TenthScreen ten;
      List<Widget> pages;

      @override
      void initState() {
        one = FirstScreen();
        two = SecondScreen();
        three = ThirdScreen();
        four = FourthScreen();
        five = FifthScreen();
        six = SixthScreen();
        seven = SeventhScreen();
        eight = EighthScreen();
        nine = NinthScreen();
        ten = TenthScreen();

        pages = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten];

        super.initState();
      } 

      final PageController controller = new PageController();

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context){

        return new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Scaffold( 
              body: new Container(
                child: new PageView.builder( //Swipe Between Pages
                  controller: controller,
                  itemCount: 10,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    return pages[index];
                  }
                ),
              ),
            ),
            new Container( //CircleIndicator
              child: new CircleIndicator(controller, 10, 8.0, Colors.white70, Colors.white,),
              alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.9),
            ),
            new Container( //Button
              alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.65),
              child: new Row( 
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Container(
                    child: new RaisedButton(
                      elevation: 4.0,
                      child: new Text(
                        'SHOW ME',
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                          fontSize: 22.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      color: Color(0xFF70E0EF),
                      shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(7.5)
                      ),
    //This is the conditional statement I'm talking about
                      onPressed: () { 
                        new PageView.builder(
                          controller: controller,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            if (pages[index] == one){
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new FirstTable()),
                              );
                            }
                            else if (pages[index] == two){
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondTable()),
                              );
                            }
                            else {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new ThirdTable()),
                              );
                            }
                          }
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    width: 150.0,
                    height: 60.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

The "Table" classes I'm referring to in the conditional statement are in the files for first.dart, second.dart, etc. Here is the file for first.dart.  For the moment, the code is identical between all these files (first.dart, second.dart, etc.):

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new First();
      }
    }

    class First extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      FirstState createState() => FirstState();
    }

    class FirstState extends State<First>{

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        double fontSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

        double fontSizeFractional = fontSize * 0.07;

        return Scaffold( 
          body: new Stack(
            fit: StackFit.passthrough,
            children: [
              new Container( //Background
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  image: new DecorationImage(
                    image: new AssetImage('assets/FirstBG.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              new Container( //Title
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(40.0), 
                alignment: new Alignment(0.0, -0.70),
                child: new Text(
                  'FIRST',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: fontSizeFractional,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: 'baron neue',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class FirstTable extends StatelessWidget {

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Table();
      }
    }

    class Table extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      TableState createState() => TableState();
    }

    class TableState extends State<Table>{
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: new Text(
                'Go Back',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

I have a theory that the reason it isn't working is that collections.dart isn't actually caching any data as to what page of the index it is on (that could be totally wrong, though).  Curious to hear your ideas!

Comment: Basically what you want is a PageView with a "More info" button under it that shows contextualized information ?

Comment: I think that summarizes it pretty well.  :) I think the complication is that the button isn’t operating conditional to what page is displayed at the moment.

Comment: Why do you instantiate a `PageView` in the `onPressed` of your button ? Why not just switch over `controller.index` ? There's no point in instantiating a `PageView` there

Comment: Although honestly I woudn't do it like that at all. Do you mind if I build something from scratch with the same objectives ?

Comment: Honestly because it was the only way I could figure out to get index to be acknowledged in the conditional statement.  No other reason. I know that isn’t great reasoning.

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter too early.  How do you switch over controller.index?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177412/discussion-between-remi-rousselet-and-trent-kennelly).

Comment: No problem at all please feel free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you should directly use `controller.page` inside the `onPressed` of your button. instead of instantiating a widget.

Although ultimately you should hide an abstract layer between your gallery class and the list of items.

To do that you can create a custom class which will hols all informations about a gallery item :

```
@immutable
class GalleryItem {
  final Widget content;
  final Widget details;

  GalleryItem({@required this.content, this.details}) : assert(content != null);
}
```

Your gallery will then take a list of such class as parameter. And do it's job with these.

Ideally you want to use your gallery like this :

```
Gallery(
  items: [
    GalleryItem(
      content: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      details: Text("red"),
    ),
    GalleryItem(
      content: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      details: Text("blue"),
    ),
  ],
),
```

[image]

The code of such gallery would be :

```
class Gallery extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<GalleryItem> items;

  Gallery({@required this.items, Key key})
      : assert(items != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _GalleryState createState() => _GalleryState();
}

class _GalleryState extends State<Gallery> {
  final PageController pageController = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: PageView(
            children: widget.items.map((item) => item.content).toList(),
            controller: pageController,
          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: showContentDetails,
          child: Text("More info"),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  void showContentDetails() {
    final index = pageController.page.round();

    if (widget.items[index]?.details != null) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) =>
            GalleryItemDetails(details: widget.items[index].details),
      );
    }
  }
}

class GalleryItemDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget details;

  GalleryItemDetails({@required this.details, Key key})
      : assert(details != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      child: details,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!